# How to modify kernel timer_list timeout

Tags: timer, linux-kernel, timeout, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I am implementing a timeout for some parameters in my kernel module.

So I am using `struct timer_list` and Associated API's to implement a 12 sec timer.

So as mentioned in the IBM developer Works guide for kernel timers I use:

```
struct timer_list my_timer;
init_timer_on_stack(&my_timer);

void tick_timer()
{
    my_timer.expires = jiffies + delay * HZ; //delay is global variable int = 12.
    my_timer.data=0;
    my_timer.function = my_timer_func;
    add_timer(&my_timer);
}
```

So each time my timer expires I do my work in `my_timer_func` and call `tick_timer` again to reset the timer.

Next, I would like to implement the `delay` as a sysctl entry.
But the change should immediately call the `tick_timer` function and reset the timer with new `delay`. SO how can I detect this change and remove any current timer or reset it.

Should there be any kernel thread to detect the change in `delay`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kernel has no mechanism for detect changes in variables. Instead, you should perform corresponded actions before/after *your* code changes *your* variable.

When you add sysctl entry, you also set handler for it(`ctl_table->proc_handler`). This handler defines actions, which are executed when read/write method for entry is called. Standard `proc_do*` functions only set/get value of variable, so you should define your handler. Something like this:

```
int my_handler(struct ctl_table *table, int write,
     void __user *buffer, size_t *lenp, loff_t *ppos)
{
    // Call standard helper..
    int res = proc_dointvec(table, write, buffer, lenp, ppos);
    if(write && !res) { 
       // Additional actions on successfull write.
    }
    return res;
}
```

Modification of the timer's timeout can be performed using `mod_timer` function.